# Converting ExpandoObject to a Type, What is more efficient and less time consuming, doing that client side or server side?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, javascriptserializer, expandoobject

***Problem Definition:***

I got an ExpandoObject that i need to convert to a Type like "Customer" Type, the problem is not achieving that, am wondering should i approach that server side or client side using javascript, i can achieve what i want both ways but which is more effective and less time consuming?

***Server Side approach:***

```
public IEnumerable<T> Convert<T>(dynamic self)
{
    List<T> model = new List<T>();
    var jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    foreach (var obj in self)
    {
        model.Add(jsSerializer.ConvertToType<T>(obj));
    }
    return model.AsEnumerable();
}
```

***Client Side approach:***

```
var model = [];
data.forEach(function (item) {
    var property = [];
    item.forEach(function (pair) {
        property[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
    });
    model.push(property);
});
```

***Used ORM:*** Rob Conery's Massive

***Original Response(No Conversion):***

> [[{ "Key": "ID", "Value": 2 }, { "Key": "customerID", "Value": 1 }, { "Key": "orderID", "Value": 1 }, { "Key": "address", "Value": "25 Ibrahim Nagy Street, NasrCity, Cairo" }, { "Key": "deliveryDateTime", "Value": "/Date(1381528800000)/" }, { "Key": "deliveryPersonnelID", "Value": 1 }], [{ "Key": "ID", "Value": 3 }, { "Key": "customerID", "Value": 2 }, { "Key": "orderID", "Value": 2 }, { "Key": "address", "Value": "14 Ibrahim Nagy Street, NasrCity, Cairo" }, { "Key": "deliveryDateTime", "Value": "/Date(1386972000000)/" }, { "Key": "deliveryPersonnelID", "Value": 2 }], [{ "Key": "ID", "Value": 4 }, { "Key": "customerID", "Value": 1 }, { "Key": "orderID", "Value": 3 }, { "Key": "address", "Value": "30 Abbas Akad Street, NasrCity, Cairo" }, { "Key": "deliveryDateTime", "Value": "/Date(1387922400000)/" }, { "Key": "deliveryPersonnelID", "Value": 2 }], [{ "Key": "ID", "Value": 5 }, { "Key": "customerID", "Value": 3 }, { "Key": "orderID", "Value": 4 }, { "Key": "address", "Value": "25 Hassan Maamoon Street, NasrCity, Cairo" }, { "Key": "deliveryDateTime", "Value": "/Date(1388354400000)/" }, { "Key": "deliveryPersonnelID", "Value": 3 }]]

Comment: It doesn't work like that with me because data is retrieved via AJAX calls and i got to deal with dynamics because my ORM is 'Massive'.

Comment: It seems like am talking to my self because the guy who asked me deleted his comment, Just great.

Comment: server side gives you compile tim

Comment: ok, that's one way to look at it, but what about the whole view?;

Comment: wouldn't straight from Expando to JSON be fastest... why the between step?

Comment: what between step?, am sorry i got lost here :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to do the conversion client side, i don't know it feels right to me, i mean let the client do some work and also it's not much of a hard work too, so why waste time server side?

Comment: Also feel free to use any code in my question if you face similar situations :D.